# AS3 Amount of Touches on screen

Tags: actionscript-3, multi-touch

Whats the limit of multitouch finger inputs possible on the screen at once?

I need 5 fingers to touch buttons on the phone's screen at once

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried this yet? I would imagine the limit would be imposed by the device, not by AS3.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, five touches works.  The maximum number varies per device but I think you get five (pretty awkward to physically do) on the phones that matter.

You can try checking the maximum touchpoints for the device using Multitouch.maxTouchPoints but I think it doesn't work on some devices.

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to assume it will work. (high end devices and tablets is quite likely yes, but many lower end devices that are older only support one, two or three touchpoints)

AIR and FlashPlayer 10.1+ have a way to find out the maximum supported touch points on the host device:

```
flash.ui.Multitouch.maxTouchPoints
```

Using this property you can alert the end-user that their device is not supported (or handle it however you'd like).

```
   if(Multitouch.maxTouchPoints < 5){
       //unsupported device
   }
```

You can read the documentation [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html#maxTouchPoints)